# Android ssl certificate error after renewing the certificate in server using digicert

Tags: android, ssl, https, ssl-certificate, x509certificate

I have been using the ssl certificate key provided by the server team in android application under raw folder.It was working fine initially.

```
     CertificateFactory cf = CertificateFactory.getInstance("X.509");

        InputStream caInputMmx = new BufferedInputStream(this.getAssets().open("123.crt"));
        Certificate caMmx = cf.generateCertificate(caInputMmx);
        String keyStoreType = KeyStore.getDefaultType();
        KeyStore keyStore = KeyStore.getInstance(keyStoreType);
        keyStore.load(null, null);
        keyStore.setCertificateEntry("caMmx", caMmx);
        String tmfAlgorithm = TrustManagerFactory.getDefaultAlgorithm();
        TrustManagerFactory tmf = TrustManagerFactory.getInstance(tmfAlgorithm);
        tmf.init(keyStore);
        SSLContext context = SSLContext.getInstance("TLS");
        context.init(null, tmf.getTrustManagers(), null);
        client.setSslSocketFactory(context.getSocketFactory());
```

After some days ,the certificate got expired and the server team renewed the certificate.From that point of time our android application stopped working with below exception

**com.android.volley.NoConnectionError: javax.net.ssl.SSLHandshakeException: java.security.cert.CertPathValidatorException: Trust anchor for certification path not found.**

On using the new renewed certificate from server our application works fine .Is there any workaround to fix this from server rather updating the new certificate in application every time ? Because if the user does not update the application , our app is not going to work. So is there any way to solve this issue instead of updating the cert in application every time if the certificate is expired .

Edited :

After comments ,  providing some additional informations .

Keystore : I am  using default keystore .
CA : I am using  digicert CA.These guys are trusted .

Answer (score 6):

This kind of problem is often caused by a missing chain certificate. Check your site against [SSLLabs](https://www.ssllabs.com/ssltest/analyze.html) and look for reports of incomplete chain. Note that desktop browser like Chrome might still work because they cache chain certificates from earlier connections and sometimes even actively try to retrieve missing chain certificates from the internet.

Comment: @pradeep.k: your code does not show the validation but only loading of the certificate. From the shown code it is not clear that you use pinning. Even with the additional information it is not clear if you are using pinning additionally to normal validation or exclusively. It is also not clear if you are doing certificate pinning or public key pinning and if the renewed certificate is using the same public key. Also, if you are exclusively do pinning then you would not need to replace the certificate on expiration at all.

Comment: @pradeep.k: if the problem is really caused by the pinning inside your application then updating the application is the only choice.

Comment: You mentioned something like  if renewed certificate is using the same public key ? I am not sure if same public key is being used .. . Any idea  if this renewed certificate uses the same public key will solve this issue ??  Although , updating the application is the only choice ,we are looking for some quick workaround ,so it will block the users , since lakhs of users are using the application currently.

Comment: @pradeep.k: how to solve the problem now and in the future depends on how exactly you do pinning. See my comment where I pointed out all the missing information and provide the missing details, preferable by editing your question and not posting it in a comment.

Comment: I have updated the code where we are doing the pinning . By the code i guess we are doing normal validation . Please correct me if am wrong . To avoid this is future we have are gonna follow some kind of solutions.What we are looking is to give a quick solution so users wont feel discomfort in using app .If we dont provide the quick solution , we may loose lakhs of users overnight .

Comment: Also , any idea like if i can do some configurations in server to by-pass this security  , so the application will work fine .

Comment: @pradeep.k: this does not look like certificate pinning but it looks like you are just adding your own CA to the key store . If this is all then you simply accept certificates which are issued by these CA. I think you need to provide more information, i.e. how the new certificate relates to the CA you trust in your application. It might also be that you add exactly the self-signed certificates you trust to the store but this cannot be seen from the code alone since contents of the added and of the used certificates is not known.

Comment: @pradeep.k: and no, you cannot bypass security by configuring something at the server. You can only make sure that the server provides trusted certificates, i.e. certificates issued by the CA in your trust store.

Comment: Thanks a ton for your quick help.We are using the key provided by a CA and new renewed is also from the same CA .When i tried  " openssl s_client -debug -connect <server>" i got below  message "Verify return code: 19 (self signed certificate in certificate chain)"  , Does this mean the server is being self signed rather the singed using renewed certificate provided by CA ?? Please correct if am wrong . .

Comment: @pradeep.k: CA's don't provide keys, they sign certificates. If the issuing CA is configured as trusted in your key store (again: this is unknown) it should work without changes to the application if the certificate is configured properly at the server. It is unknown too if this is the case. And again, please add any details needed to answer the question to the question and not in a comment. Ideally one would need information about the certificates you load as trusted, about the leaf certificates and any chain certificates sent by the server and their relation to the trusted CA.

Comment: thanks for your guide :) As per the code , if you see  the certificate provided by for CA is being trusted for our default keystore using TrustManagerFactory .So , its like  for old certificate we have added the trust , but after renewal a new certificate is being used in server provided by the same CA.

Comment: @pradeep.k: if the CA you use is trusted as you say then the server setup is messed up. For example it might be missing a chain certificate like I proposed in my initial response. Since you are using a public CA please check against SSLLabs (see original response).